# Sequences of Binyanim with Infinitive Construct

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk

We find in *Tanakh* the grammatical construction: **infinitive absolute + finite verb**, where the two verbs are of the same root.  For example, in Genesis 22:17, we have two occurences (text and translation from [Mechon Mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0122.htm#17):

> כִּי-**בָרֵךְ אֲבָרֶכְךָ**, וְ**הַרְבָּה אַרְבֶּה** אֶת-זַרְעֲךָ כְּכוֹכְבֵי הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְכַחוֹל, אֲשֶׁר עַל-שְׂפַת הַיָּם; וְיִרַשׁ זַרְעֲךָ, אֵת שַׁעַר אֹיְבָיו
>
> that in blessing I will bless thee, and in multiplying I will multiply thy seed as the stars of the heaven, and as the sand which is upon the seashore; and thy seed shall possess the gate of his enemies

This construction is often used for emphasis (see another question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/verb-its-infinitive)).

Normally, the infinitive and the finite verb are in the same *binyan*, for example:

*qal + qal*: [Gen 2:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm#16),
*nifal + nifal*: [Gen 17:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0117.htm#13),
*piel + piel*: [Gen 22:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0122.htm#17),
*pual + pual*: [Gen 40:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0140.htm#15),
*hifil + hifil*: [Gen 3:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0103.htm#16),
*hofal + hofal*: [Josh 9:24](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0609.htm#24),
*hitpael + hitpael*: [Num 16:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0416.htm#13).

However, there are occasions where the infinitive is in *qal*, even though the finite verb is not.  For example:

*qal + nifal*: [Ex 19:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0219.htm#13),
*qal + piel*: [2 Sam 20:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b20.htm#18),
*qal + hifil*: [1 Sam 23:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a23.htm#22),
*qal + hofal*: [Gen 26:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0126.htm#11),

along with a small number of other cases (as mentioned in [Gesenius 113w](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/113._The_Infinitive_Absolute)).

**Question**: Are there differences of meaning between the consistent *binyan* construction and the mixed *binyan* construction? Are there any commentators (or grammarians) who discuss a difference in meaning between the two cases?

Comment: I may need some clarification on the focus / scope of your question.  It looks like the infinite (1st) verb is always qal. The 2nd verb depends on the exact meaning that needs to be conveyed. The 1st & last verses in your list have to be passive / causative to fit the context and proper meaning. Are you asking spec. why the infinite verb is always qal in these cases?

Comment: @DanF The first verb is not always _qal_.  In general, any _binyan_ has this construction, but the mixed _binyan_ construction seems to be productive with _qal_ as the infinitive (and there are isolated other cases where the infinitive is not _qal_).   I'm not sure I understand the rest of your comment.