# ידע תדע what kind of knowing is this?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, parashat-lech-lecha

In a couple of verses like [Genesis 15:13](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0115.htm#13), [1 Samuel 28:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a28.htm#1), [1 Kings 2:37](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a02.htm#37), [2:42](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a02.htm#42) and [Proverbs 27:23](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2827.htm#23) we find two verbal repetition: 'ידע  תדע' quite literally translated as 'knowing you will know'. I know that a repetition of the same word with a change in form of one of the words is used for emphasis, and I once read that this double use of 'knowing' would indicate an active form of knowing, and would be a reference to the past and future.

So what's the meaning of this combination, what does it refer to, which kind or form of knowing is meant by it?

Comment: Cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2329

Comment: AFAIK ידע is more accurately translated as *understand*