# A list of doubled words

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, product-recommendation, hebrew

In the tanach, there are times when certain words are doubled (generally verbs but I'm open to other combinations) with one form of the word, followed by a second form which is in a future tense, I think. The fact that the words are doubled often opens the text up to exegetical understanding, the way the Ramban understands [Bereishit](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.17?lang=bi&aliyot=1&p2=Ramban_on_Genesis.2.17.1&lang2=bi) 2:17.

I am trying to get a list of all instances like this to see if there is a consistent interpretive approach. So far, I have sh-ch-kh, a-b-d, m-t, h-r-g, z-ch-r, m-kh-h, kh-r-sh as roots to which this occurs, but is there a comprehensive list already available so I can start reviewing the verses?

Comment: Check out Bava Metzia 31

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks -- that's a start. It added 11 (and possibly 12 -- I have to check) more but didn't include at least 2 that I already had and one other I just thought of. This makes me worry that there are even more I am missing.

Comment: I also just found 2 that are post biblical, but Talmudic so I would be happy to compile a parallel list and see if I can generalize my understanding from category to another.

Comment: Why would it be important that the second word is in the future tense? Is Genesis 31:30 not the kind of syntax you're looking for?

Comment: @ba I'm not sure. Your example also leads me to 2 separate ones for g-n-b. I'll take all tenses and then break them up afterwards I guess.

Comment: I found a list of this a long time ago. If I can dig up the article I’ll post it as an answer. I believe it listed 81 across the five Chumashim.

Comment: The "roshi roshi" of the dying child in Elisha's story cycle in II Kings 4(:19 onward) should be added to the list.  That always seemed to me to be a perfect expression of anguish"My head!My head!"

Comment: There is Hineini hineini in Yeshayahu and the haftorah that begins anochi anochi, but these are a separate category I think.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/verb-its-infinitive

Comment: @DonielF Thanks in advance. I am up to 39. 4 are talmudic/post biblical, 1 is a name and 3 reflexive. I fear that "names" would lead me down a rabbit hole.

Comment: @DonielF I now have 45 distinct roots (with many different iterations of some of them) with 28 being in the Chumash, 14 in the nevi'im and 3 in ketuvim. Plus I have 1 just in the talmud and 1 from elsewhere. I am sticking with verb forms (I started on names and reflexive words like anochi but that's too much and noun-verb situations don't have the same interpretive possibilities). I just need to find a place to share it.

Comment: Aha! I’ve got it! The article is online [here](http://www.mishpacha.com/Browse/Article/244/Age-Old-Questions-Modern-Day-Solution). But...you need a subscription... I can’t view them, but if someone else can, have fun.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1czFd_Ek2WgjdW1sGpoX9zKy17UmsOD6dVnrkVuWM0y4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm at 65 of this specific type of root doubling, plus a bunch of nouns or other combinations.