# Drashos based on the doubled verb

Tags: hebrew, midrash, grammar-dikduk

In [Menachos 17b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.17b.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the gemara explains a drasha:

> ור"א א"כ לכתוב רחמנא אם האכל האכל א"נ אם יאכל יאכל מאי האכל יאכל שמעת
> מינה תרתי
>
> And what would Rabbi Eliezer respond? He would say that if that were
> so, that the verse intends to teach only that halakha, let the
> Merciful One write either: If he’akhol he’akhol, or: If ye’akhel
> ye’akhel, repeating the same form of the word twice. What is the
> reason that the verse states “he’akhol ye’akhel,” employing both
> repetition and variation? Learn from this formulation two halakhot.

Rashi:

> מאי האכל יאכל - מדשני קרא בדיבורא. שמעת מינה תרתי - למחשבת הקטרה
> בכזית ומחשבין מאכילה לאכילה

I've seen this setup in a number of gemaras (see also [verb + its infinitive](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/verb-its-infinitive)). Here Rashi says that the drasha, like any drasha, is based on a "שינוי": It could have just doubled the verb directly, so from the fact that the two verbs have different forms we can learn a drasha.
I don't know much grammar, but isn't this difficult? Am I wrong in thinking that there are hundreds of these doubled verbs in Tanach, and every single one has the same structure: first an infinitive form, then the regular verb. I think. If so, this is not the שינוי; doing it the other way with just a straight repetition would be a שינוי and a unique one.
Does someone explain this, or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94452/a-list-of-doubled-words

Comment: Is it possible that Rashi intended the "repeat" sense of שני? https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99.1?lang=bi&with=all

Comment: @rosends tl;dr :) What is the upshot: Are there examples of simple repeated verbs?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Rashi seems to be explaining the implication of _not_ simply repeating.

Comment: I think you are right on the pshat level; Rashi is working on the drush level.